# List more than 1000 objects in Google Cloud Bucket console ls

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to return a list of all files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket via console.

When I use

```
gsutil ls -r gs://<my_bucket>
```

It only returns ~1000 or so objects, despite there being ~16,000 objects in the bucket.

Anyone have any ideas of how to get around this 1000 objects(?) limit?

Just need a list of all objects in the bucket.

Comment: The API limits the number of results when listing objects to approximately 1000 per API request, with a continuation token to fetch the next set. However, gsutil operates 1 level up from there, and iterates over the continuation tokens, so you should be seeing all the objects in the bucket.

Have you tried running `gsutil -d ls -r gs://<my_bucket>`
That will show you the requests/responses, and may provide a clue about what's happening in your case.

Comment: Are you using an old version of gsutil? Try updating first and then repeat the command **gcloud components update**. The command in your question will list all objects in a bucket.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz After running with '-d' can see a token call of some sort at ~300 or some sort, then a few more file names, but still maxing at around ~1000 lines of code. Could this be because i'm using gsutil from the cloud shell inside the Google console?

Comment: Tried your `gsutil` command on my bucket with more than 2000 objects and it listed all the objects. I am using `gsutil version: 5.5`.

Answer (score 1):

If following along at home the solution was to use Googles cloud shell editor and output the list as a file. The below code worked once in the full page editor (mainly to be able to access the output file).

```
gsutil ls -r gs://<bucket_name_path>/** > new_file.txt
```

Hopefully this helps anyone coming across a similar issue.